# How do you marshal a line break in Go YAML?

Tags: go, yaml, command-line-interface

In a golang CLI I'm programming I collect information on how to configure the tool and I marhsal that as a YAML file. However, I'm not sure how I would add line breaks to make the file more readable?

```
type Config struct {
    Author  string `yaml:"author"`
    License string `yaml:"license"`
    // Marhsal a line break here
    Workspace   string `yaml:"workspace"`
    Description string `yaml:"description"`
    // Marhsal a line break here
    Target string `yaml:"target"`
}
```

Comment: that CLI generates a config file, and you want it to have spaces dividing some segments? how about having them under different parents? like `Config > group 1 > Author, License`; `Config > group 2 > Workspace, Description`, and so on...

Comment: YAML is a representation of structured data – you give structured data in and get a YAML representation of that data out. Additional line breaks do not contribute to the structured semantics of a YAML file. Therefore, you cannot express your desire to create line breaks as a part of the data structure you serialize. `yaml.v3` does allow you, with much hardship, to add lines with an empty quote (`#`) but I seriously advice against doing that. If you want precise control of your data's representation, YAML is simply the wrong tool for you.

Comment: @germanio yes, exactly

Comment: how about a template engine?

Comment: A template engine would work. I'm not as familiar with the Go ecosystem yet. @germanio, what do you suggest?

Comment: @Adgezaza let me play a bit with it to see how it would look like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to implement this that allows format (and comments) is to use a template engine.

Here is a running example that generates a string with the formatted yaml, that can be then saved to a `.yml` file.

No additional libraries are needed and the template is included inside the go file.

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "text/template"
)

type Config struct {
    Author      string
    License     string
    Workspace   string
    Description string
    Target      string
}

const cfg_template = `
conf:
    author: {{ .Author }}
    licence: {{ .License }}

    workspace: {{ .Workspace }}
    description: {{ .Description }}

    # you can even add comments to the template
    target: {{ .Target }}

    # other hardcoded config
    foo: bar

`

func generate(config *Config) string {
    t, err := template.New("my yaml generator").Parse(cfg_template)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
    err = t.Execute(buf, config)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return buf.String()
}

func main() {
    c := Config{
        Author:      "Germanio",
        License:     "MIT",
        Workspace:   "/home/germanio/workspace",
        Description: "a cool description",
        Target:      "/home/germanio/target",
    }
    yaml := generate(&c)

    fmt.Printf("yaml:\n%s", yaml)
}
```

The result looks like this:

```
$ go run yaml_generator.go 
yaml:

conf:
        author: Germanio
        licence: MIT

        workspace: /home/germanio/workspace
        description: a cool description

        # you can even add comments to the template
        target: /home/germanio/target

        # other hardcoded config
        foo: bar
```

I'm sure there are better ways to implement it, just want to show a quick working example.

Answer (score 1):

As empty line don't have a meaning in yaml, the default library does not create them, and does not expose an option to do so in the struct field tag.

However, if you want fine grained control of how a type is marshalled in yaml, you can always make it implements `yaml.Marshaller` by defining a method `MarshalYAML() (interface{}, error)`